# How to download and add an image to a card when selected?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

When a card is selected in a `CardScrollView`, the `onItemSelected()` method is called.  However, I cannot determine how to add an image to this card once selected.  For now, I've done a kluge callback mechanism where I call `updateViews(true)`:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (position == mSelectedPosition)
        return;
    mSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mCardScrollView != null)
        mCardScrollView.updateViews(true);
}
```

Then in the adapter `getView()` I check if the item is selected, and if so load the image asynchronously:

```
if (mCardScrollView != null && mCardScrollView.getSelectedItemPosition() == pos) {
    String url = String.format(Board.THUMBNAIL_FORMAT, board, tim);
    CardImageLoader.loadCardImage(card, Card.ImageLayout.FULL, url, mCardScrollView);
}
```

The `CardImageLoader` then downloads the file and does yet *another* call to `updateViews()` after the download is successful, finally calling `card.addImage()` and the image displays.

This works, but can make things slow at times, and sometimes unresponsive.  How to do it better?

UPDATE: Don't use a Card when you need to load a list of cards with images in a CardScrollView.  Instead, use your own custom layout to emulate a card and use a standard image loader to do the loading.  This works much better even with very long lists.

Google please make the card layout XMLs open so we can use them.

Comment: If you create a custom layout instead of using a card, can you still use CardScrollView?

I'm guessing the answer is yes, because it probably just converts the cards into views, correct?  Just wanted to confirm.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it works, it uses the view layout you give.

Answer (score 0):

If you've kept hold of the list of cards you initialize the `CardScrollView` with (i.e. mCards from https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui/theme-widgets#creating_scrolling_cards_in_activities) and then just get the card from that position in the list, update it and call `.invalidate()` on it to refresh the view, that should work from `onItemSelected`.

Comment: Don't want to keep the list of cards in memory, I have hundreds.